# xpath: select nth item returns all

Tags: xslt, select, xpath

When I use the xpath select as per the xslt below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="urn:ROCK-BlueScope/ShipmentImportWS"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ManifestSourceM>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns:Shipment/ns:ShipmentInformation">
            <DSManifest>
                <ManifestNo>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:GeneralShipmentInformation/ns:ShipmentIdentificationNumber"></xsl:value-of>
                </ManifestNo>
                <ManifestDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:DateTimeReference/ns:Date"></xsl:value-of>
                </ManifestDate>
                <PrimeMover>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop/ns:EquipmentDetails[ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:DescriptionCode = 'TV'][1]/ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:EquipmentNumber"></xsl:value-of>
                </PrimeMover>
                <Fleet1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop/ns:EquipmentDetails[ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:DescriptionCode = 'TL'][1]/ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:EquipmentNumber[1]"></xsl:value-of>
                </Fleet1>
                <Fleet2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop/ns:EquipmentDetails[ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:DescriptionCode = 'TL'][2]/ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:EquipmentNumber[2]"></xsl:value-of>
                </Fleet2>
                <Fleet3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop/ns:EquipmentDetails[ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:DescriptionCode = 'TL'][3]/ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:EquipmentNumber[3]"></xsl:value-of>
                </Fleet3>
                <Fleet4>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop/ns:EquipmentDetails[ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:DescriptionCode = 'TL'][4]/ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:EquipmentNumber[4]"></xsl:value-of>
                </Fleet4>
                <Fleet5>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop/ns:EquipmentDetails[ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:DescriptionCode = 'TL'][5]/ns:EquipmentStructure/ns:EquipmentNumber[5]"></xsl:value-of>
                </Fleet5>
                <RouteCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns:GeneralShipmentInformation/ns:StandardCarrierAlphaCode"></xsl:value-of>
                </RouteCode>
                <Description><xsl:value-of select="string-join(('BlueScope Load:', ns:GeneralShipmentInformation/ns:ShipmentIdentificationNumber, ' On RunCode:', ns:GeneralShipmentInformation/ns:StandardCarrierAlphaCode), '')"></xsl:value-of>
                </Description>
                <Description2></Description2>
            </DSManifest>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </ManifestSourceM>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And apply it to this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:Shipment xmlns:ns="urn:ROCK-BlueScope/ShipmentImportWS">
    <ns:ShipmentInformation Transaction="Actual">
        <ns:GeneralShipmentInformation>
            <ns:TransactionSetPurposeCode>00</ns:TransactionSetPurposeCode>
            <ns:TransportationMethodTypeCode>L</ns:TransportationMethodTypeCode>
            <ns:ShipmentMethodOfPayment>DE</ns:ShipmentMethodOfPayment>
            <ns:ShipmentIdentificationNumber>178896</ns:ShipmentIdentificationNumber>
            <ns:StandardCarrierAlphaCode>NUNCOL</ns:StandardCarrierAlphaCode>
        </ns:GeneralShipmentInformation>
        <ns:Priority>0</ns:Priority>
        <ns:DateTimeReference SegmentId="StartTime">
            <ns:Date>2010-12-09</ns:Date>
            <ns:Time>07:00:00</ns:Time>
        </ns:DateTimeReference>
        <ns:Origin>
            <ns:GeographicLocation>
                <ns:LocationIdentifier>NUN</ns:LocationIdentifier>
            </ns:GeographicLocation>
        </ns:Origin>
        <ns:Destination>
            <ns:GeographicLocation>
                <ns:LocationIdentifier>~COMPLETE STEEL ROOFING</ns:LocationIdentifier>
            </ns:GeographicLocation>
        </ns:Destination>
        <ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
            <ns:EquipmentDetails>
                <ns:EquipmentStructure>
                    <ns:Initial/>
                    <ns:EquipmentNumber>Z26GW</ns:EquipmentNumber>
                    <ns:DescriptionCode>TV</ns:DescriptionCode>
                </ns:EquipmentStructure>
            </ns:EquipmentDetails>
        </ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
            <ns:EquipmentDetails>
                <ns:EquipmentStructure>
                    <ns:Initial/>
                    <ns:EquipmentNumber>B16KY-5</ns:EquipmentNumber>
                    <ns:DescriptionCode>TL</ns:DescriptionCode>
                </ns:EquipmentStructure>
            </ns:EquipmentDetails>
        </ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
            <ns:EquipmentDetails>
                <ns:EquipmentStructure>
                    <ns:Initial/>
                    <ns:EquipmentNumber>B16KY-4</ns:EquipmentNumber>
                    <ns:DescriptionCode>TL</ns:DescriptionCode>
                </ns:EquipmentStructure>
             </ns:EquipmentDetails>
        </ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
            <ns:EquipmentDetails>
                <ns:EquipmentStructure>
                    <ns:Initial/>
                    <ns:EquipmentNumber>B16KY-2</ns:EquipmentNumber>
                    <ns:DescriptionCode>TL</ns:DescriptionCode>
                </ns:EquipmentStructure>
             </ns:EquipmentDetails>
        </ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
            <ns:EquipmentDetails>
                <ns:EquipmentStructure>
                    <ns:Initial/>
                    <ns:EquipmentNumber>B16KY-3</ns:EquipmentNumber>
                    <ns:DescriptionCode>TL</ns:DescriptionCode>
                </ns:EquipmentStructure>
             </ns:EquipmentDetails>
        </ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
        <ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
            <ns:EquipmentDetails>
                <ns:EquipmentStructure>
                    <ns:Initial/>
                    <ns:EquipmentNumber>B16KY-1</ns:EquipmentNumber>
                    <ns:DescriptionCode>TL</ns:DescriptionCode>
                </ns:EquipmentStructure>
             </ns:EquipmentDetails>
        </ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop>
    </ns:ShipmentInformation>
</ns:Shipment>
```

I get this. The Fleet1 element contains all the occurences.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ManifestSourceM>
    <DSManifest>
        <ManifestNo>178896</ManifestNo>
        <ManifestDate>2010-12-09</ManifestDate>
        <PrimeMover>Z26GW</PrimeMover>
        <Fleet1>B16KY-5 B16KY-4 B16KY-2 B16KY-3 B16KY-1</Fleet1>
        <Fleet2/>
        <Fleet3/>
        <Fleet4/>
        <Fleet5/>
        <RouteCode>NUNCOL</RouteCode>
        <Description>BlueScope Load:178896 On RunCode:NUNCOL</Description>
        <Description2/>
    </DSManifest>
</ManifestSourceM>
```

I even tried with a for-each-group and choose...when specific to each occurence, but still got the same result.

I couldn't work out how to use this in the choose...when method.

```
<xsl:number count="EquipmentDetailsLoop[normalize-space(EquipmentDetails/EquipmentStructure/DescriptionCode)='TL']" level="single"></xsl:number>
```

Comment: Are you sure there will *always* be exactly 5 "Fleets"?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an expalanation and for a short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reduce example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns="urn:ROCK-BlueScope/ShipmentImportWS"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*">
    <xsl:template match="ns:Shipment">
        <ManifestSourceM>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ManifestSourceM>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:ShipmentInformation">
        <DSManifest>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </DSManifest>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:ShipmentIdentificationNumber">
        <ManifestNo>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </ManifestNo>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:Date">
        <ManifestDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </ManifestDate>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:EquipmentStructure[ns:DescriptionCode='TV']">
        <PrimeMover>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentNumber"/>
        </PrimeMover>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:EquipmentStructure[ns:DescriptionCode='TL']">
        <xsl:variable name="vNumber">
            <xsl:number count="ns:EquipmentStructure[ns:DescriptionCode='TL']"
                        level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="Fleet{$vNumber}">
            <xsl:value-of select="ns:EquipmentNumber"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ManifestSourceM>
    <DSManifest>
        <ManifestNo>178896</ManifestNo>
        <ManifestDate>2010-12-09</ManifestDate>
        <PrimeMover>Z26GW</PrimeMover>
        <Fleet1>B16KY-5</Fleet1>
        <Fleet2>B16KY-4</Fleet2>
        <Fleet3>B16KY-2</Fleet3>
        <Fleet4>B16KY-3</Fleet4>
        <Fleet5>B16KY-1</Fleet5>
    </DSManifest>
</ManifestSourceM>
```

**Note**: Overwriting text node built-in rule. Pattern matching any element we want to only transform (higher hierarchy) or transform and output value (leafs). Data driven elements names with `xsl:element` instruction. Hierarchy numbering with `xsl:number` instruction.

Comment: Thank you yet again Alejandro for clearing my headache. I've had to make some changes relating to the Date element as it was picking up all instances (the real xml contains much more data). I just removed it from being a template and added it as a normal value-of within the DSManifest node. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tony J: You are welcome. About `ns:Date` pattern: use a more specific one like `ns:DateTimeReference/ns:Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop
 /ns:EquipmentDetails
  [ns:EquipmentStructure
        /ns:DescriptionCode = 'TL'
  ][1]
      /ns:EquipmentStructure
        /ns:EquipmentNumber[1]
```

This selects the wanted `ns:EquipmentNumber` from *all* `ns:EquipmentDetailsLoop` subtrees.

Because you are using XSLT 2.0, the `<xsl:value-of>` instruction outputs one text node with the string value of every node in the node-set, selected by the `select` attribute. Thus all 4 strings are output.

**You want**:

```
(/*/*/*/*/*[ns:DescriptionCode='TL']/ns:EquipmentNumber)[$k]
```

where `$k` is in the range (must be substituted once by every integer in this range):

`1` to `count((/*/*/*/*/*[ns:DescriptionCode='TL']/ns:EquipmentNumber))`

Comment: Now you've made me somewhat uncertain about my answer. Wasn't this expression only returning the first match in XPath 1.0?

Comment: @biziclop: If you mean the OP's expression, it selects every child of any already selected node -- this is true for both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0. Maybe you are referring to the fact that in XSLT 1.0 (not XPath), the `<xsl:value-of>` instruction only uses the first node of the node-set selected by its `select` attribute. Yes, this is true. However, the OP is using XSLT 2.0, where `<xsl:value-of>` outputs one text node for *every* node in the node-set.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre for the explanation.

Comment: @Tony-J: You are welcome. Here at SO the accepted form of gratitude is accepting an answer (by clicking on the green check-mark next to the answer). :)